# How to make two column to repeat for one item in the list?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there possible for the angular repeat to achieve that?Basically Im wondering there is a way to loop the 2  together? Really appreciate any help!

Controller:

```
$scope.date=[
    {ID:1,Date:'2016-11-12'},
    {ID:2,Date:'2016-11-15'},
    {ID:3,Date:'2016-12-06'}
]
```

HTML:

```
<table border="1" align="center">   
    <tr>            
        <th rowspan="2">ITEMCODE</th>
        <th rowspan="2">DEBTORCODE</th> 
        <th colspan="2" ng-repeat="d in date">{{d.Date}}</th>   
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <th>Bal</th>
        <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I wish the column Bal and Order will repeat side by side under each date column.
[image: And I expect the column Bal and Order will repeat side by side]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end which was introduced in Angular 1.2

```
<th ng-repeat-start="d in date">Bal</th>
<th ng-repeat-end>Order</th>
```

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/9ve3fu0m/

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a nested table like this:

```
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">ITEMCODE</th>
  <th rowspan="2">DEBTORCODE</th>
  <th colspan="2" ng-repeat="d in date">
    <table border="1" >
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">{{d.Date}}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bal</th>
        <th>Order</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end

```
<table border="1" align="center">   
<tr>            
    <th rowspan="2">ITEMCODE</th>
    <th rowspan="2">DEBTORCODE</th> 
    <th colspan="2" ng-repeat="d in date">{{d.Date}}</th>   
</tr>       
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat-start="d in date">Bal</th>
    <th ng-repeat-end>Order</th>
</tr>
```